# My NetBeans installation fails to run my simple application

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have a problem with Netbeans. It does not run my code, and I am sure my code is correct.  Here is what NetBeans looks like when I try to run:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO3Wn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, check your JDK version. Maybe it not compatible with your NetBeans version.
if are you installed the correct version, configure JDK in your system.

control panel -> system -> advanced system setting ->environmental variable(in Advanced tab) ->Now you can see the list of paths. So click on the new button and copy the path of JDK where you installed JDK. By default, it will be such as “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin”. Then paste the path and click OK -> Now under the user variables section, Click on New button. new user variable window will open. In variable name, type JAVA_HOME into it and variable value, give the path “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221” and click on OK. Then again click on OK.